# Confused about JavaScript prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

In the book "**JavaScript the definitive guide 5 edition**", section 9.2 Prototypes and Inheritance, I find the following words:

> In the previous section, I showed that
>   the new operator creates a new, empty
>   object and then invokes a constructor
>   function as a method of that object.
>   This is not the complete story,
>   however. After creating the empty
>   object, new sets the prototype of that
>   object. The prototype of an object is
>   the value of the prototype property of
>   its constructor function. All
>   functions have a prototype property
>   that is automatically created and
>   initialized when the function is
>   defined. ***The initial value of the
>   prototype property is an object with a
>   single property. This property is
>   named constructor and refers back to
>   the constructor function with which
>   the prototype is associated.*** (You
>   may recall the constructor property
>   from Chapter 7 ; this is why every
>   object has a constructor property.)
>   Any properties you add to this
>   prototype object will appear to be
>   properties of objects initialized by
>   the constructor.

Now, if that is true, how could prototypal inheritance exists? I mean, let's say the prototype object of a constructor function has a constructor property initially. Because the prototype object itself is an object, to determine its constructor we often use `prototype_object.constructor`. But now the `prototype_object` already has a `constructor` property itself, and it points to ***the constructor function with which the prototype is associated***. In this situation how can inheritance exists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let say, Dog is a Mammal.

```
function Mammal() {
  this.milk = true;
};
```

function Dog() {
  this.bark = true;
}
Dog.prototype = new Mammal;

So prototype of Dog points to **an object of Mammal**. This Mammal object has a reference to its constructor so when Dog is new, JavaScript see that Dog prototype is a Mammal so Mammal's constructor is called to produce a valid Mammal object (another one) then make it a Dog object using Dog constructor.

From this, the constructor of `Dog.prototype` is a `Mammal` (a Mammal Object that has extra fields and functions added) BUT constructor of `Dog` is `Dog`. The inheritance exist because the an instance of Dog has a Mammal as a prototype; hence, Dog is a Mammal. When a method is called and JS cannot find it from `Dog.prototype`, JS look in `Mammal.prototype` (which is an Object that has extra fields and functions added).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, based on the code you've written, `var d = new Dog(); if(d.constructor === Dog) console.log('yes!') else console.log('oh noes!')` will log `oh noes!`. This is because you have overwritten `Dog.prototype` with a `Mammal` object, so `d.constructor` will point back to `Mammal`. A common pitfall that makes `.constructor` unreliable.

Comment: `Dog.prototype = new Mammal;` is a well-known anti-pattern.

Answer (score 15):

The `.constructor` property honestly doesn't matter very much, and has very little to do with inheriting from other objects in JavaScript. It's just a convenient handle to an object's constructor.

For example, if you have an instance of something, and you'd like to create another instance of that thing, but you don't have a direct handle on its constructor, you could do something like this:

```
const myCar = new Racecar();
console.log(myCar.constructor); // [Function: Racecar]

const car2 = new myCar.constructor();
console.log(car2.constructor); // [Function: Racecar]
```

It's important to understand that the `.constructor` property and the class of an object are not synonymous. As you may have already guessed, the `.constructor` property is dynamic, just like most other things in JavaScript, so it should not be used for anything like type checking.

It's also important to understand that the `.constructor` property does not mean that something is a subclass of something else. In fact, there is no reliable way to find out if something is a subclass of something else in JavaScript. Because it's a dynamic language, and because there are so many ways to inherit properties from other objects (including copying properties from other objects after instantiation), type-safe subclasses don't exist in JavaScript like they exist in other languages.

The best way to know if something is a compatible type is to feature-test properties. In other words, duck type.

The `instanceof` operator ignores the `.constructor` property. Instead, it checks whether or not the constructor's `.prototype` exists (with an identity check) in the prototype chain of the object.

With manual constructor functions, inheritance can confuse the `.constructor` property connection (making it refer to the wrong constructor). You can fix it by manually wiring up the connection. For example, the canonical way to do so in ES5 is this:

```
function Car () {}

console.log(Car.prototype.constructor); // Car

function Racecar () {}

Racecar.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype);
// To preserve the same relationship we have with the Car
// constructor, we'll need to reassign the .prototype.constructor:
Racecar.prototype.constructor = Racecar;

var myCar = new Racecar();
console.log(myCar.constructor); // [Function: Racecar]
```

ES6 classes do this for you automatically:

```
// ES6
class Car {}
class Racecar extends Car {}

const myCar = new Racecar();
console.log(myCar.constructor); // [Function: Racecar]
```

That said, I'm not a big fan of either constructor functions or ES6 classes, and I generally have little use for the `.constructor` property. Why? Because factory functions are far more flexible, far more powerful, and they don't have the pitfalls related to constructor functions and class inheritance. See ["Factory Functions vs Constructor Functions vs Classes"](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-factory-functions-vs-constructor-functions-vs-classes-2f22ceddf33e).

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about the constructor property - it is irrelevant. 
Skip those sentences and you might follow it better.

If you are still unsure of your understanding, google for __proto__ - the internal prototype reference on JS objects. It is even exposed to scripts on Firefox and Safari.

A good reference is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/The_Employee_Example/Object_Properties/Inheriting_Properties

Answer (score 1):

If you have an object `obj`, it's prototype is `obj.prototype` and constructor property referring to `obj`'s constructor is `obj.prototype.constructor`.

For the object `obj.prototype` the situation is the same. Let's say `proto = obj.prototype`, then the reference to the constructor of `proto` would be found at `proto.prototype.constructor`.

This is the same as `obj.prototype.prototype.constructor`, so there is no conflict with `obj.prototype.constructor`.

Comment: `obj.prototype` is not to prototype of `obj`. if `obj = new XYZ` then `XYZ.prototype` is the prototype of `obj`.