# Clarifying JavaScript prototypes

Tags: javascript, prototype, language-concepts

Suppose I have a child function:

```
function Child() {}
```

and have a parent function:

```
function Parent() {}
```

then I set the Child's prototype to a new instance of Parent:

```
Child.prototype = new Parent()
```

the confusion is each time when I create new an instance of Child

```
var c = new Child()
```

Would the Parent be created again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Confused about JavaScript prototypal inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182685/confused-about-javascript-prototypal-inheritance)

Comment: No, `Parent` is not created again. It is created once, when `new Parent()` is called, to set `Child.prototype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is created only once.  Every time you call `new Child()` a new `Child` object is created and the same `Parent` object is set to be its prototype.  You can confirm this by doing the following ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GTyGS/1/)):

```
function Child() {}
function Parent() {
    this.aParentProp = { name : "Parent" };
}
Child.prototype = new Parent();
var c1 = new Child();
var c2 = new Child();

if(Object.getPrototypeOf(c1) === Object.getPrototypeOf(c2)) {
    alert("same prototype!");
}

if(c1.aParentProp === c2.aParentProp) {
    alert("same property!");
}
```

Both `c1` and `c2` have the same `prototype` using [Object.getPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).  Also, both `c1`'s and `c2`'s `aParentProp` points to the same object instance showing that both `c1` and `c2` share the same `Parent` object for their `prototype`.